# Getting particular data from CLOB

Tags: oracle

I have below data in `CLOB` column, and I want to get `xyz.com` from below data. `DOMAIN NAME LIST` will not change and it will be same all the time

```
{
    "OBJECT ID":"71864756",
    "OBJECT NAME":"MESSENGER",
    "PARENT ID":"71865529",
    "OBJECT STATUS":"O",
    "WHITE LISTED":"N",
    "LAST UPLOAD":"",
    "PARENT CLASS":"ORDER",
    "IS A LINK OBJECT IND":"N",
    "AOL IM FEDERATION":"false",
    "ATTRIBUTE 1":"0",
    "ATTRIBUTE 2":"0",
    "ATTRIBUTE 3":"0",
    "ATTRIBUTE 4":"0",
    "ATTRIBUTE 5":"0",
    "CLASSIC CENTER INTEGRATION URL":"",
    "COMMENTS":"",
    "DISPLAY NAME":"",
    "DOMAIN NAME LIST":"xyz.com",
    "ICON NAME":"SERVICE_16.PNG",
    "IM LICENSES":"500",
}
```

Please help me by using `dbms_lob.substr`.....

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40766/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( json CLOB )
/

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (
  '{"OBJECT ID":"71864756","OBJECT NAME":"MESSENGER","PARENT ID":"71865529","OBJECT STATUS":"O","WHITE LISTED":"N","LAST UPLOAD":"","PARENT CLASS":"ORDER","IS A LINK OBJECT IND":"N","AOL IM FEDERATION":"false","ATTRIBUTE 1":"0","ATTRIBUTE 2":"0","ATTRIBUTE 3":"0","ATTRIBUTE 4":"0","ATTRIBUTE 5":"0","CLASSIC CENTER INTEGRATION URL":"","COMMENTS":"","DISPLAY NAME":"","DOMAIN NAME LIST":"xyz.com","ICON NAME":"SERVICE_16.PNG","IM LICENSES":"500"}'
)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         json,
         '[{,]"DOMAIN NAME LIST":"((\\.|[^"])*)"',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS domain_name_list
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40766/2/0)**:

```
| DOMAIN_NAME_LIST |
|------------------|
|          xyz.com |
```

Comment: I am getting data as oracle CLOB datatype and i cannot change it to JSON CLOB. Is there any other way to get by using dbms_lob funcation with substr?

Comment: @EdwardThomas - the data type here is still CLOB; the column *name* in the example is `json` (perhaps slightly confusingly, but makes sense in context as you didn’t specify your own name). You’ve misread the table create statement.